# Deleing List Item Recalculates Mail Count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a mail box menu which you can right-click and choose to delete a folder which looks a bit like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Level 1
        <span class="badge badge-success MailCount">60</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Level 2 a
                <span class="badge badge-success MailCount">10</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Level 2 a i
                        <span class="badge badge-success MailCount">10</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Level 2 b ii
                        <span class="badge badge-success MailCount">10</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Level 2 c iii
                        <span class="badge badge-success MailCount">10</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Level 2 b
                <span class="badge badge-success MailCount">10</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                Level 2 c
                <span class="badge badge-success MailCount">10</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my Javascript file looks like the following;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {

        var action = $(e.target).data('action'),
            anchor = '',
            clicked = $('.clicked'); // This is applied when you right-click teh item

        switch (action) {
            // Rename a mail sub-folder...
            case 'rename-folder':

                break;
        }

    });
});
```

So at this point in time, all I simply do is `clicked.remove();` however now I'd like to take the `.clicked > .MailCount` value and take it away from all `.MailCount` above and if `.clicked` has direct `ul` which are going to also be deleted, their values should be added up with the current and removed from the above value.

I hope I haven't made that sound more complicated than what it is. Basically if you remove `Level 2 a`, it'll add up `Level 2 a` + `Level 2 a i` + `Level 2 a ii` + `Level 2 a iii` and take them away from `Level 1`

Comment: Why are you attaching the handler to `document` instead of something like `$(".rename-folder").click(...)`?

Comment: If it's because the elements get added dynamically, you should use event delegation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Why isn't `Level 2 a i + Level 2 a ii + Level 2 a III` included in `Level 2 a`?

Comment: What happens if they delete `Level 2 a ii`? It looks like we should subtract its mail count from `Level 1`, but not from `Level 2 a`. How does it know which parents to subtract from? Is the total only in `Level 1`?

Comment: @Barmar I do it like this as it is better for how the rest of my file has been scripted. The folder count is on all leading up to the deleted item if available (this is only an unread message count). So deleting `Level 2 b ii` would subtract `Level 2 b ii`'s value from `Level 2 a` and `Level 1`

Comment: But it doesn't look like `Level 2 a ii` is included in `Level 2 a`. Shouldn't `Level 2 a` be at least 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Got this eventually working using the following:

```
case 'delete-folder':
    var thisUnread = clicked.find('.MailCount:first').text();
    clicked.parents('li').each(function() {
        var parentUnread = $(this).find('.MailCount:first').text();
        if ((parentUnread - thisUnread) > 0 ) {
            $(this).find('.MailCount:first').text((parentUnread - thisUnread));
        } else {
            $(this).find('.MailCount:first').remove();
        }
        clicked.remove();
    });
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()` to loop over all the `.MailCount` elements in the `li` being removed and add up all their contents.  Then subtract it from the total in the top-most `.MailCount`.

```
var remove_total = 0;
clicked.find(".MailCount").map(function() {
    remove_total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
});
clicked.parents("li").last().find(".MailCount").first().text(function(i, oldText) {
    return parseInt(oldText, 10) - remove_total;
});
clicked.remove();
```

Comment: See [here](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/Account/Messages_New.html#) for a live demo. Going over the entire script as it needs to be done so didn't want to post this really and regarding how I've mapped my list above, I mocked this up before and a bit under the weather - It is meant to be 30!

Comment: Thank you for this help, I'll go over it once I get some food inside of me so I can focus more! I've rated your answer up and will hopefuly accept it as an answer soon.

Comment: If each level includes all the children counts, then we should just subtract the current level from the total, not the current level and the children, because then we're subtracting the children twice.

Comment: Wow, I'm going for a break, what a complete and utter stupidity moment! Just subtract `clicked.find('.MailCount')` from `clicked.parent().find('.MailCount')` as the closest `.MailCount` would already show the count for all the children!

Comment: You actually need to subtract it from the first `.MailCount` in each `.parents("li")`

Comment: I'm getting an error from your snippet `Uncaught ReferenceError: oldTesxt is not defined(...)`

Comment: Hiya @Barmar, I've been trying to go through your code to resolve this problem as this method is going to be used in multiple places however I've not been successful and could do with your help please.

Comment: You have a typo. `oldTesxt` should be `oldText`.

Comment: My above comment was a typo, I was meant to say `Uncaught ReferenceError: oldText is not defined(...)` Please see my answer, I've got this working :)

Comment: Barmar, wouldn't it be simpler to just take a new total count? If we know the list is complete, then that seems simpler.  If it's not, then obviously that wouldn't work.

Comment: I had a typo in the answer, `oldtext` versus `oldText`. I was also missing one of the arguments.

Comment: Regenerating all the counts from scratch is certainly another way to do it.

Comment: Yours now gets the top level count and alters it but not any parents along the way. Also if you want to get this working, please add comments as I don't understand this method and it would be very useful to be able to do so. Thanks

Comment: My answer is based on the HTML in the question, where only the top-level count includes the children. You should edit the question to show what it's really like.

Comment: Each level shows the total unread mails so if a folder has sub-folders, then that folder shows the total for the sub-folders within. Let's just say add some commenting so I can understand what you've done such as the `+=`?

Comment: Level 2 a doesn't have the total for Level 2 a i/ii/iii in it. Fix the question to match reality.